# Interpret input as string and class member name

Tags: python

In a few `__init__` of different classes I have to use several times the construct

```
try:
    self.member_name = kwargs['member_name']
except:
    self.member_name = default_value
```

or as suggested by Moses Koledoye

```
self.member_name = kwargs.get('member_name', default_value)
```

I would like to have a method that inputs, say, the string `'member_name'` and `default_value` and that the corresponding initialization gets produced. For example, if one inputs `'pi_approx'` and `3.14` the resulting code is

```
self.pi_approx = kwargs.get('pi_approx', 3.14)
```

In this way I can replace a long sequence of these initializations by a loop along a list of all the required members and their default values.

[This technique emulate a switch statement](https://bytebaker.com/2008/11/03/switch-case-statement-in-python/) is not the same thing but kind of has a similar flavor.

I am not sure how to approach what I want to do.

---

Assuming that `initializer(m_name, default_val)` is the construction that gets replaced by

```
self.m_name = kwargs.get('m_name', default_val)
```

I would then used it by having a lists `member_names = [m_name1, m_name2, m_name3]` and `default_values = [def_val1, def_val2, def_val3]` and calling

```
for m_name, d_val in zip(member_names, default_values):
    initializer(m_name, d_val)
```

This would replace long list of try's and also make the code a bit more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `try/except` was meant to handle `KeyError`, then you can use the `get` method of the kwargs dict which allows you to supply a default value:

```
self.member_name = kwargs.get('member_name', default)
```

Which can be extended to your list of attribute names using [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr):

```
for m_name, d_val in zip(member_names, default_values):
    setattr(self, m_name, kwargs.get(m_name, d_val))
```